# How to swipe lot of pages using ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist, android-viewpager

I have a Employees class contain basic information like this

```
public class Employees{
      private String name;
      private String adress;

      public Employees(String name, String adress){
         this.name = name;
         this.adress = adress;
      }

      public String getName() {

         return name;
      }

      public String getAdress() {

         return adress;

      }

}
```

And I have a Arraylist contain employees object with arraylist size is about 1000 object. I want to use viewpager (one page display one object, not scroll view) and when I swipe page then I can see employees info in ArrayList.

Comment: You can find everything you need from [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)'s documentation

Comment: read this document. 
http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html